# Copy and append files to a remote machine: cat error

Tags: ssh, append, scp, cat

So, I have a bit of a problem:

Originally I was using `scp` to copy a file from a local machine to a remote machine before I realized that scp overwrites instead of appends. But I need it to append. So I did some Googling and this alternative using `cat` and `ssh` popped up instead:

```
cat localfile | ssh user@remoteserver "cat >> remotefile"
```

Problem is, I get this interesting error whenever I use that method:

```
bash: cat: command not found
```

When I normally ssh into my remote machine, I can `cat` just fine, so I'm looking for either help fixing this problem or finding a way to append using only commands from my local host.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$PATH` may be different when running through ssh.

Anyway, you can run `which cat` to find where `cat` is actually placed on the remote machine and hard code the path in the command invocation. For instance

```
ssh user@remoteserver "/sbin/cat >>remotefile" <localfile
```

(BTW, you don't really need the local `cat`).

Another option would be to use a SFTP client with support for appending.